# sql how to write select where

Tags: sql

I have a table of users where we have a columns which contains UserID and bookId, but users can read one book twice or more and db saves this result every time. how can I get users who read 1 book more than 1 time? Thx

Comment: Please post the DB structure with a sample in.

Comment: What is the column name for no of times book read?

Comment: `select UserID, Count(*) FROM Users
    WHERE BookId = xxx
    Group By UserId, BookId
    Having (Count(*) > 1)` from what I understand you need something like that.

Comment: Exactly one book read more than one time? Or at least one book read more than one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implying your table name is "users2books".

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT UserID, count(bookID) as 'number' from user2books
  GROUP BY UserID
) a
WHERE number > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Then the count of unique bookid's would be different compared to the count of bookid's for that user.

```
SELECT UserID
FROM YourBooksReadByUsersTable
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(BookId) > COUNT(DISTINCT BookId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a `GROUP BY` to return UserId's that have read a book more than once.

Do `select distinct` just in case a user has read several books more than once. (On of the rare cases when you combine `group by` with `select distinct`!)

```
select distinct UserID
from tablename
group by UserID, BookId
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One user can read more than one book ,more than one time so, its more realistic if we have both field.

```
select userid,Bookid from tablename
group by userid,bookid
having count(*) > 1;
```

else if we only want to have user id then **jarlh** answer we can follow.